# Justifying Text in HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I am looking to show justified text within a HTML table (for use in an email signature).

What I am hoping to achieve is:

[image: Justified text]

However, what I am getting so far is:

[image]

The code looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JohnDoe</title>
<style> 
    #contentTable{
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-right: 35px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        padding-left: 35px;
        width: 480px;
        height: 105px;
    }

    #nameRow{
        height: auto;
    }

    #nameField{
        font-size: 24;
        font-family: "Helvetica";
        color: #73A84D;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #dirRow{
        height: auto;
    }

    #dirField{
        font-size: 18;
        font-family: "Helvetica";
        color: #606062;
    }

    .descRow{   
    }

    .descField{
        font-size: 10;
        font-family: "Helvetica";
        font-weight: 900;
        color: #96989A;
    }

    .valueField{
        font-size: 10;
        font-family: "Helvetica";
        font-weight: 900;
        color: #606062;
        text-align: justify;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <table id="contentTable">
        <tr>            
            <td>
                <table id="infoTable">
                    <tr id="nameRow">
                        <td id="nameField">JOHN DOE</td>    
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="dirRow">
                        <td id="dirField">
                            Attorney
                        </td>   
                    </tr>                   
                    <tr>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p id="descFieldPara" class="descField">
                                        PHONE:<br>
                                        EMAIL:<br>
                                        &nbsp;<br>
                                        URL:
                                    </p>                                
                                </td>
                                <td id="valueFieldPara" class="valueField">
                                    <p>+ 12 3456 789 012<br>JOHN.D@BLAHBLAH.COM.US<br>ATTORNEY@BLAHBLAHJOHNDOE.COM.US<br>WWW.BLAHBLAHJOHNDOE.COM.US
                                    </p>    
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do? Why is it that despite using `text-align: justify;`
I don't get what I want?

Comment: <opinion>Justified text like that looks awful. Consider left and right aligned text.</opinion>

Comment: It's because of you `<br />`'s

Comment: @zgood Please look at my response comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what are you trying to achieve?

**I'm not the owner of the code

http://jsfiddle.net/B4Y2u/

It seems it need a bit of trick:

```
div {
  text-align: justify;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because of how you have it laid out with `<p>` and `<br>`'s. If you are using a table then why don't you make use of multiple rows?

ex:

```
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="descField">
                            PHONE:                          
                        </td>
                        <td class="valueField">
                            + 12 3456 789 012 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="descField">
                            Email
                        </td>
                        <td class="valueField">
                            JOHN.D@BLAHBLAH.COM.US
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

**UPDATE**

Ok here is a CSS hack to allow for 1 line of justified text:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2jam0w8r/)

The key here is that the `<p>` tags in the table cells are getting content injected at the end of the element to fake a second line and force the text to become justified. I then set the `<p>` height and line-height to smaller value that matched the font-size so it would align with the other cell text.

```
    .valueField p {
        text-align: justify;
        width: 100%;
        height:10px;
       line-height:10px;
       margin:0;
    }
.valueField p:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I had tried that already. That does not work at my end. How does the snippet you posted above look on your browser? As I am given to understand, 'justify' implies that multiple lines in a para will take the same space. It does not make sense for a single line of text in a single row. Hence the attempted hack from my part of putting multiple lines in a single <p>.

Comment: Ok I understand. I will put together Fiddle of CSS that will achieve this.

Comment: I have updated the answer and removed the `transform` that I was using earlier

Answer (score 0):

I can't view those images

This tells you how http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_p_align.asp

for example

```
p {
align:justify;
}
```